# Django Model error in function

Tags: django, django-models

My problem is this.

for example the following code. The console throws me an error about not finding the model 'ModelB'.

```
class modela(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=360)

    def print_name_modelb(self):
        modelb = modelb.objects.get(id=1)
        print modelb.name

class modelb(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=360)
```

Is there any way to set up all the empty models for use in function if the recognition?

---

Edit with real data.

```
class Vip2ProductosPlantilla(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=360)
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    intro = models.TextField()
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    precio_tienda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    precio_vip = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    precio_cesion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    zoom = models.BooleanField()
    id_marca = models.ForeignKey(Vip2Marcas, null=True, db_column='id_marca', blank=True)
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Vip2Categorias)
    stock  = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    gastos_envio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)

    def get_precio(self):
        try:
            precio = MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla=self)[0]
            if (precio != None) & (precio.precio_ml > 0):
                print 'precio ml'
                return precio.precio_ml
            else:
                print 'precio vip'
                return self.precio_vip
        except:
            print 'precio vip error'
            return self.precio_vip

class MLPreciosProductos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    plantilla = models.ForeignKey(Vip2ProductosPlantilla,null=True, db_column='plantilla', blank=True)
    precio_ml = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    campana = models.ForeignKey(Vip2Campanas, null=True, db_column='campana', blank=True)
```

when the template function call get_precio, the exception is thrown

---

```
Traceback:
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/opt/marketland.es/web/marketland/views.py" in outlet_campana
  127.         context_instance=RequestContext(request))    
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  227.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  90.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  510.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  653.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  698.                             current = current()
File "/home/opt/marketland.es/web/marketland/models.py" in get_precio
  201.         precio = MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla=self)[0]
File "/home/opt/ENV-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  190.             return list(qs)[0]

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /outlet/atornillador-blackampdecker-pilas-aaa-558/
Exception Value: Caught IndexError while rendering: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are those both in the same file, as you have shown them here?

Comment: Have you done: 'python manage.py syncdb'

Comment: yes, I have all the models in the same file

Comment: OK, can you show the exact error message with the traceback, please.

Comment: sorry I misspoke. I meant that when the template use myobjectmodela.print_name_modelb, jump exception. ModelB guess that is defined later, or not has nothing to do?

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you get an exception, please post that. So far you did not give enough information for anybody to answer your question.

Comment: I added more information in question

Comment: But you didn't show the error and traceback, as you were requested twice. In fact, I see that you have a bare `except` in that function, which means the error will be swallowed. Don't do that, as it makes debugging impossible, as we see here. Remove that try/except and post the exception here.

Comment: I edited again. but the fault is now giving because the attempt to make "precio = MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla=self)[0]" or find one

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to define `modelb` before `modela` in the same file.
Python is a script language and is executed line by line, so when you refer to `modelb` in your example, it does not exist yet.
However, sometimes you need two models to refer to one another in the `ForeignKey`, in such case, you can pass the name of the model as a string:

```
 campana = models.ForeignKey('Vip2Campanas')
```

Another thing which may cause issues is filtering giving an object in:

```
MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla=self)
```

Because objects can change dynamically and are, in fact, pointers, it's better to identify objects by their id like this:

```
MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla_id=self.id)
```

or use reverse lookup which django creates behind the scenes:

```
Foo(models.Model):
    pass

Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')

# instance of a Foo model is given 'hidden' field bar_set 
foo.bar_set
```

`(modelname)_set` is added automatically and allows to fetch the list of all entries linked to the object by the foreign key.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your last your comment,

"I edited again. but the fault is now giving because the attempt to make `precio = MLPreciosProductos.objects.filter(plantilla=self)[0]` or find one"

i think you cannot filter with just `self` try change it with `self.id` or `self.nombre` whatever you want as long as it is defined on the class. Excuse my bad English, just trying to help

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

If I can filter by self. Now everything works fine and I do not know why. Just added to my try / except this line to display the console exepcion print '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))